# nodeJS mySql UPDATE

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a problem for `UPDATE` with mySql.
I want to update the number of views of my web page.
NodeJS does not crash, but nothing happens. No insertion in the database.

```
var userCount = 0;
//ROUTE ARTICLE
app.get('/articles_'+$random_id, (req, res) => {
    //VARIABLE URL
    var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    if (pathname != "/favicon.ico") {
        userCount++;
    }//FIN COMPTEUR DE VUE
    //VARIABLE INSERT NBR VUE INTO TABLE VIEWPOST
    connection.query('UPDATE viewpost SET nbr_vues ? WHERE number_post = ?', [userCount, number_post], function (err, results) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("nbr_vues updated");
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this UPDATE statement to increment your view count in your table.

```
UPDATE viewpost SET nbr_vues = nbr_vues+1 WHERE number_post = ?
```

Or maybe this one to use the logic in your program

```
UPDATE viewpost SET nbr_vues = ? WHERE number_post = ?
```

Notice that the correct UPDATE syntax is this. You were missing the `=` in `col = val`.

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = val, col = val WHERE number_post = ?
```

It is possible there is no row in your table `WHERE number_post=?`. In that case your UPDATE will update zero rows. That's a valid operation in SQL and will not give you back any error.  Maybe you should try this SQL.

```
INSERT INTO viewpost (nbr_views, number_post) VALUES (1, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nbr_views = nbr_views+1;
```

That will create a row for your number_post, and increment it if it already exists.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I'm going to try.

Comment: It works !!
A big thank-you.
This is the '=' that I had forgotten.
But I am going to study the other proposals you made to me, they are interesting

Comment: @frédéricaveline See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work